# List contents of text file in alphabetical order?

Tags: windows, sorting

I have a txt file with about 3000 name entries on each line. I want to list them in alphabetical order.

Is there any way I can do this via some text editor so that i don't have to manually go through all the names in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple command that's included with Windows XP (as that's what I'm assuming you're running from your tag) called `sort`.

It's as simple as running `sort FileToSort.txt /o OutputFile.txt` in `cmd` [replacing `FileToSort.txt` with the file you want sorted and `OutputFile.txt` with the name of the file you want to output] (start -> run -> cmd; see [here](http://www.veign.com/code-view.php?type=app&codeid=107) for more examples and usage).

Comment: You know, I have been using Windows for years and years. I knew about the Unix sort command, uniq, etc. but never once thought to try it on Windows!

Comment: "sort in.txt out.txt" doesn't work. You'll need to use "sort in.txt /o out.txt" or "sort in.txt > out.txt"

Comment: @Bavi_H: Thanks, answer revised to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

[PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/) has a line sorting feature: **Edit** -> **Sort...**

[ConTEXT](http://www.contexteditor.org/) has a similar sorting feature.

Or if you can cope with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), that has a built-in sort command which works on a range of lines, or on the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a program...

pseudocode (assumes each name is on its own line):

```
names as List of Strings
while(!file.eof)
{
    names.Add(file.readline());
}

names.Sort();
```

Comment: this would be a better fit if the question were asked on SO. just a thought.